# install OpenFaaS to your Kubernetes Cluster on Minikube issue

Tags: django, networking, cloud, openfaas

while install OpenFaaS to your Kubernetes Cluster on Minikube getting some URL issue.

```
C:\Users\XXX\openfaas\faas-netes>helm upgrade --install --debug --reset-values --set async=false --set rbac=false openfaas openfaas

[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '60216'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:60216"
```

Error:

> Non-absolute URLs should be in form of repo_name/path_to_chart, got:
>   openfaas

Help me to slove the following issue.

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason why the install isn't working is the name of the chart. To install it using the chart, your command should be

```
helm upgrade --install --debug --reset-values --set async=false --set rbac=false openfaas/openfaas
```

*So with a "/" between the two occurrences of openfaas at the end*

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the Chart with arkade (fastest option)

The arkade install command installs OpenFaaS using its official helm chart, but without using tiller, a component which is insecure by default. arkade can also install other important software for OpenFaaS users such as cert-manager and nginx-ingress. It's the easiest and quickest way to get up and running.

You can use arkade to install OpenFaaS to a regular cloud cluster, your laptop, a VM, a Raspberry Pi, or a 64-bit ARM machine.

```
# For MacOS / Linux:
curl -SLsf https://dl.get-arkade.dev/ | sudo sh

# For Windows (using Git Bash)
curl -SLsf https://dl.get-arkade.dev/ | sh
```

Install the OpenFaaS app If you're using a managed cloud Kubernetes service which supplies LoadBalancers, then run the following:

```
arkade install openfaas --load-balancer
```

Note: the --load-balancer flag has a default of false, so by passing the flag, the installation will request one from your cloud provider.

If you're using a local Kubernetes cluster or a VM, then run:

```
arkade install openfaas
```

After the installation you'll receive a command to retrieve your OpenFaaS URL and password.

Other options for installation are available with arkade install openfaas --help

For cloud users run

```
kubectl get -n openfaas svc/gateway-external
```

and look for EXTERNAL-IP. This is your gateway address.